# Bash Autocomplete Subdirectory for Custom Command

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, autocomplete, tab-completion

I have tried for hours to get this working and feel like I've not come anywhere close.

I am trying to shorten our workflow by tab-completing directory names from the Mac OS X Terminal.

We have an internal tool, let's call it `bob`, that automatically runs commands on git submodules. What I'd like to do is get it to autocomplete the subdirectory names. The problem is, those subdirectories live in a static location.

```
   project directory
   ->public
     ->submodules
       ->a-module
       ->another-module
       ->other-module
       ->some-module
```

Commands are run from the top project directory like so:

```
bob start bugfix anothermodule
```

Rather than having to fully type out 'anothermodule', which is what we currently do, I'd love to get tab autocomplete to work. We use this workflow many times per day and shaving seconds off of it would be great and avoid typos.

The end goal is:

```
bob start bugfix an<tab>
```

would autocomplete to

```
bob start bugfix anothermodule
```

I've tried `CDPATH` but quickly realized this was not what I'm after, as this isn't following the `cd` command, only my custom command.

I have `bash_completion` installed but I am not very good at bash in general. Mentioning this though in case it can be a part of the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an enhancement of [Kamil’s excellent answer](https://superuser.com/a/1269174/247588) that strips the hyphen from the `-module` part of each sub-directory name.

```
bugfix)
    curdir=$(pwd)
    cd public/submodules/ 2>/dev/null && _filedir -d
    # Strip the hyphen from `-module` in each sub-directory name.
    for ((i=0; i<${#COMPREPLY[@]}; i++)); do
        COMPREPLY[$i]="${COMPREPLY[$i]/-module/module}"
    done
    cd "$curdir"
    ;;
```

There’s still scope for improving this section: you may have to type the hyphen, i.e., type <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to get it to complete to `amodule` instead of a choice between `amodule` and `anothermodule` (the hyphen is still stripped by the completion function).

Comment: I think if you replace `COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -d -- "$cur" ) )` with just `_filedir -d` then your code will handle directory names with spaces better.

Comment: Many thanks @KamilMaciorowski  I've been using the `bash-completion` package for so long that I had thought the space handling was built into `compgen`.

Answer (score 4):

That's right, `bash_completion` is a solution. I can tell you what I have in my Ubuntu. I hope things are at least similar on Mac.

There is `/etc/bash_completion` file which sources `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`.

In a directory `/usr/share/bash-completion` there's also a `completions` subdirectory. This is the place for scripts. Let's look at the `eject` script:

> ```
> # bash completion for eject(1)                             -*- shell-script -*-
>
> _eject()
> {
>     local cur prev words cword
>     _init_completion || return
>
>     case $prev in
>         -h|--help|-V|--version|-c|--changerslot|-x|--cdspeed)
>             return
>             ;;
>         -a|--auto|-i|--manualeject)
>             COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W 'on off' -- "$cur" ) )
>             return
>             ;;
>     esac
>
>     if [[ $cur == -* ]]; then
>         COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '$( _parse_help "$1" )' -- "$cur" ) )
>         return
>     elif [[ $prev == @(-d|--default) ]]; then
>         return
>     fi
>
>     _cd_devices
>     _dvd_devices
> } &&
> complete -F _eject eject
>
> # ex: ts=4 sw=4 et filetype=sh
> ```

Even without reading the documentation we could reverse-engineer it a little and adjust to your case. For us the most important part of the above code is where it says that after `-a`, `--auto` `-i` or `--manualeject` there can be either `on` or `off`. In your case after `bugfix` you need a directory name.

(Or not. You have `another-module` directory but you use `anothermodule` argument. For now I assume it's a typo. In case it's not, [Anthony's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1269950/432690) will point you in a right direction, I think.)

We could somehow extract these directories you want and replace `'on off'`, but it may be better to utilize the existing code. After I type `cd`, `bash` autocompletes directories, and it works well even if there are spaces or special characters. So let's look at `_cd()` function; it's in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, I won't paste it here. Next it seems the crucial part of this function is `_filedir -d` invocation. Just before where `_filedir()` is defined, we have:

> ```
> # This function performs file and directory completion. It's better than
> # simply using 'compgen -f', because it honours spaces in filenames.
> ```

Bingo.

So I copied the `eject` script under the name `bob` and edited to the form of:

```
# bash completion for bob                             -*- shell-script -*-

_bob()
{
    local cur prev words cword curdir
    _init_completion || return

    case $prev in
        bob)
            COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W 'start stop foo bar' -- "$cur" ) )
            return
            ;;
        start)
            COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W 'bugfix' -- "$cur" ) )
            return
            ;;
        bugfix)
            curdir=$(pwd)
            cd public/submodules/ 2>/dev/null && _filedir -d
            cd "$curdir"    
            ;;
    esac

} &&
complete -F _bob bob
```

Existing `bash` sessions won't notice this file, you have to run a new `bash` to test it.

**Yes, it's quick and dirty voodoo programming, sorry.**

Notice we descend to `public/submodules/` and go back. Normally I would use a subshell:

```
export -f _filedir
( cd … && _filedir -d )
```

but it looks like `_filedir` won't work this way.

Comment: Great answer: I like how you modify a pre-existing completion function. It does what the OP wants -- aside from removing the hyphen. I have seen some software projects where the name of a component does not match its corresponding name in the filesystem so it may not be a typo. Since comments aren’t suitable for code-blocks, I’ve posted my modifications as a [separate answer](https://superuser.com/a/1269950/247588).

Comment: You’re welcome. A while ago, I followed a couple of tutorials to implement some basic custom completions using `compgen` and friends but I didn’t get too far with it. I found your approach of hacking the functions provide by `bash_completion` to be  educational and practical.